# Are Verilog always blocks synthesized so that the sensitivity list items are settled by the time the block behavior is carried out?

Tags: fpga, verilog, hdl, synthesis, programmable-logic

In other words, if `signal` goes high and triggers the `always` block, will the block be synthesized in a way that the behavior in the `if (signal)...` block is reliably performed (since `signal` is now high)? Or will this behavior only be reliably performed after a `clk` rising edge when `signal` is already high?

```
always @ (posedge clk, posedge signal)
begin
    if (signal)
    begin
        // do stuff 
    end
end
```

I've simulated similar code in Active-HDL, showing that `// do stuff` is performed after a `signal` rising edge.

My prior experience with HDL makes me uneasy about this code, but I'm new to Verilog and wanted to clear up any misconceptions.

**Related questions:**

- Is synthesis of code like this vendor-specific?
- Are VHDL sensitivity lists
  handled in a markedly different way?

---

I am trying to implement something like a SPI slave peripheral, so the two important inputs are the chip select and the clock. Since the clock will only ever be used a relatively long time before and after the chip select changes state, I'm using them both in the sensitivity list with the chip select being essentially an asynchronous set, as you suggest. Ordinarily I'd bring signals in synched with a shift reg to sequence behavior, but I don't have access to a particularly fast clock, so I'm trying to understand better to create a safe way to sequence things.

Comment: Regarding your VHDL sensitivity list, general verilog simulation isn't deterministic, VHDL simulation is: https://insights.sigasi.com/opinion/jan/vhdls-crown-jewel.html

Comment: What about synthesis? Can I not expect consistent behavior of the code in the example from vendor to vendor? It seems crazy that consistent behavior of the same code would not be part of the spec.

Comment: It's not crazy, HDLs are just that: description languages. Tool vendors will work hard to deliver consistent synthesis and simulation results, and you can expect them as long as you don't stray *too* far from general coding idioms. Consistent is not necessarily the same as what you expect, though.

Comment: You can't build hardware that depends on two separate clocks (i.e., edges on two different signals), except in the specific idiom in which one of them is used strictly as an asynchronous set/reset. Even then, the HDL does not capture all of the details about the hardware timing, such as setup/hold times and reset recovery times. That's why you also need static timing analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the clock will only ever be used a relatively long time before and after the chip select changes state, I'm using them both in the sensitivity list with the chip select being essentially an asynchronous set...

Yes, that's fine. But there are no guarantees. If the SPI master violates the setup/hold timing of CS with respect to CLK, there's nothing you can do about it.

> Is synthesis of code like this vendor-specific?

No, not normally.

> Are VHDL sensitivity lists handled in a markedly different way?

The syntax is different, but in the end, they both represent the same hardware.

Comment: Still, if a positive edge of `signal` triggers the always block, there is no way to know the state of `signal` without doing timing analysis?

Comment: @schadjo This strikes me as an odd question. You shouldn't be using an edge-trigger signal as part of combinational logic inside the same block.

Comment: @Elliot - I agree with you, but it's not clear why this is prohibited beyond thou-shalts and hand-waving. If `signal` will always be high when the block behavior occurs, always be low, or is not knowable, great, but which is it, and why? So far I have not seen a satisfactory answer in my reading and asking.

Comment: The only thing that a clocked `always` block guarantees (i.e., the "block behavior" in your terms) is that certain variables (FFs) will be updated when the clock edge occurs. Whether they get updated with valid values depends on the logic around those FFs, and whether that logic meets the timing constraints of the FFs. THAT's what static timing analysis tells you. It's starting to sound as if you've made your question so abstract that you yourself don't understand what it really means. Perhaps you should provide a more concrete example of what you're talking about.

Comment: Haha, it is totally true I don't know what I'm talking about, but every pearl of wisdom helps. Let me put together a more informative edit.